# merge nodes with the same name via xslt

Tags: xslt

I try to change my XML-File via XSLT. 
The file is like:

```
<A1>
<A2>
<A3>
<b>a</b>
<b>b</b>
...
</A3>
</A2>
</A1>
<A1>
<A2>
<A3>
<b>1</b>
<c>2</c>
</A3>
</A2>
</A1>
...
```

The result should be:

```
<A1>
<A2>
<A3>
<b>a, b</b>
</A3>
</A2>
</A1>
<A1>
<A2>
<A3>
<b>1</b>
<c>2</c>
</A3>
</A2>
</A1>
```

Could anybody help me with that?!!!!
Regards

Comment: So, what is the logic behind merging? Please edit your question and describe it.

Comment: I've changed the question. I'm not sure if I can describe this. The nodes with the same name should be combined (merged as in exp.) but not all the nodes only one with the name of b. The problem is: The xml-files doesn't have the same structure. That means sometimes b has 3 "parents" some times 2, 4, .... Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends greatly on a number of things that you haven't mentioned, like are the children elements always in order (i.e. will it always be `<b><b><c>` or might it be `<b><c><b>`) and are the elements always the children of the `<A3>` element.

For the above XML I've written a template to process the  element as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="A3">
    <A3>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[name()=current()/name()] and not(preceding-sibling::*[name()=current()/name()])">
                        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                        <xsl:for-each select="self::* | following-sibling::*[name()=current()/name()]">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="not(following-sibling::*[name()=current()/name()]) and preceding-sibling::*[name()=current()/name()]">
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </A3>
</xsl:template>
```

There is probably an easier way of doing this but this is one way at least. It might be slow depending on the number of children elements you have for a particular node.